# Firebug cd equivalent in Chrome console / developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

In firebug, you can use the `cd` command to change the console context to an iframe. I need this when developing a facebook app to debug my javascript inside the iframe.

How do you do this in google chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No "cd" command yet, but it seems that we'll have a "dropdown list with all iframes to allow selecting current evaluation context for console expressions" in upcoming releases.

See http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/91839